# Ubuntu 10.10 says Sandisk 8GB pendrive not partitioned?

Tags: ubuntu, usb, usb-flash-drive

Ubuntu doesn't automatically open my Sandisk 8GB pen drive when I insert it....

It was working very well until yesterday...mysteriously Ubuntu stopped opening it...When I go to `System -> Administration -> Utility`, although it is recognized,says 'Not partitioned'

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at it in GParted (which you might have to install first). It'll tell you if something's screwy with the partitions.

**EDIT:**

If so, the situation isn't good. You can use `dd` to make a backup in case you figure out a way to recover the data, changing `sdx` to the correct device and the `of=` filename to your desired backup image name:

```
dd if=/dev/sdx of=/output/file.img
```

Basically, though, your partition table is probably corrupted. The only thing I know to do, absent some specialized tools which may or may not exist, is to delete the partition table and create a new partition(s). Of course, doing this will completely erase your flash drive; hence the backup I mentioned above.

Comment: Checked with Gparted...It says USB drive-Partition and Filesystem as unallocated with a warning "/dev/sdb-Unrecognized disk label " ...

Comment: @ZAK: I've updated my answer to address your comment.

Comment: Thnx...When i popped it in Windows,they asked me to format it,So the partition table is corrupted..I have formatted & created new partition...